# How to deploy node api in IIS7?

Tags: node.js, iis

I have node js api and it works when starting using nodemon from node terminal. Now I want to deploy it to IIS. How can I do it? Please reply, it is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run `Node.js` apps on IIS on Windows, `iisnode` module is needed. Please follow [this article](https://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode) to get going. Primary requirement to run your Node.js app on Windows is the iisnode module. If you follow the instructions carefully, you can get it working pretty quickly.

PS: You would also need to assign user `IIS_IUSRS` READ permissions to the folder (and its parent folder) which contains your Node.js API sources. `web.config` which mentions the iisnode module is very important for everything to work smoothly.

Comment: I installed iisnode module on my comp , but dont know how to deploy my api beacuse I can not find web.congfig in my node api and how to assign read permission. Can u give more detail if fossbile?

Comment: You would need to add a new `web.config` with its contents as listed the article.

Comment: After that, giving permissions is simpler. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#securing-resources).

Comment: I solved it , than you very much, You saved my time .